# Convert date format in Serializer

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying my data like this.. Can someone suggest a way to display the last date as `February 02,2023` using serializer?

```
"category": {
          "data": {
          "id": "81",
          "attributes": {
                  "id": 81,
                  "name": "ggg",
                  "last_date": "2023-02-22",
                  "created_at": "2023-02-15T13:01:53.341+05:30",
                  "updated_at": "2023-02-15T13:01:53.341+05:30",
                  }
              }
       }
```

I have tried adding below in my serializer.. but it is not working

```
attribute :last_date do |object|
      object.last_date&.to_s(:date)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) like this:

```
attribute :last_date do |object|
  object.last_date&.strftime('%B %e, %Y')
end
```

When you use the same format at other places in your application too, then you might want to give it a proper name in

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:us_date_format] = '%B %e, %Y'
```

Which would allow you to use this format with [`to_fs`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_fs) like this in your app:

```
attribute :last_date do |object|
  object.last_date&.to_fs(:us_date_format)
end
```

Comment: I would just parse and localize the timestamps on the client side.

Comment: That is actually a great idea too, @max, because the format of the date in the view is certainly a view concern and depending on the location of the user or the type of frontend application.